# Правило выбора квалификатора ресурсов

Tags: java, android

Имеются папки `values` и `values-xhdpi` .

в `values-xhdpi`

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="radioButton_text_size">50sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

в `values`

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="radioButton_text_size">14sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

На экране xxhdpi выбирается ресурс из `values-xhdpi` , на экране hdpi тоже ресурс из `values-xhdpi`,  так в каком случае из дефолтной `values` будут ресурсы браться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это немного не так работает. У системы есть своя логика как находить наиболее подходящий ресурс, она зависит от конфигурации устройства, приоритетов самих квалификаторов, после идет логика подходит ли такие папки, и рекурсия. Получается в вашем случае система не исключила папку по конфигам устройства, после у вас указывается одна лишь папка где виден density (xhdpi), и она считает что она больше подходит чем, def папка у которой нет квалификаторов вовсе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Решение**
Если хотите сохранить свою логику выбора density, вам необходимо переопределить именно подходящий ресурс, те вы создадите values-hdpi там этого параметра не будет, и в след проверке возьмется def папка values

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources?hl=ru#BestMatch

Comment: я читал эту документацию, там описано логика выбора квалификаторов, но о логике выбора между xhdpi, hdpi и т.д. сказано, мало. Читал, что андроид предпочтет ресурс с большим dpi ресурсу с меньшим, если требуемого ресурса нет. Ваше решение я никак не могу понять. Например моя ситуация, мне нужно только для hdpi экрана использовать альтернативный ресурс, а всё остальное должно быть из def папки. Но андроид для любых случаев возьмет из папки hdpi, def хоть удаляй.  Решение, которое я увидел, это создать для остальных dpi папки и там указать, то значение, что есть в def.

Comment: переопределите все папки с density и оставьте их без параметров, что здесь сложного в понимании? Тогда у вас будет из def браться, я не знаю как ещё подробней это объяснить. Просто прочтите ещё раз мб

Comment: скорее вы не вникли в проблему. Я могу оставить без параметров все density, кроме hdpi. (hdpi и все что ниже должны брать ресурс из этой папки, все остальные из дефолтной) Но пока есть хоть одна папка с параметром в def не попасть. Единственный способ во всех остальных папках определить дефолтный параметр, это поможет, но это бред, не логично. Я так понимаю, этот квалификатор не создан для реализации нужной мне логики. Есть квалификатор sw, он совершенно не работает. Установил квалификатор sw480dp и думал, что если ширина экрана меньше 480 пикселей будет из этот папки ресурс браться. но нет..

Comment: Ну так в ответе вам это и объясняю, я понял проблему это стандартная ошибка многих разработчиков которые начинают работать с ресурсами. Поэтому сразу написал, что это работает не так, как вы хотите. sw это ScreenWidth выбор МИНИМАЛЬНОЙ! доступной ширины. Те  values-sw600dp это 1024x600 mdpi те это будет скорей всего 7+ tablet. Я поинмаю по начал мб не всё понятно, но попробуйте разобраться перед тем как писать, что что-то не работает. Как правило чаще всего происходит просто недопонимания правил системы под которые нам необходимо подстроиться.

Comment: Я уже много раз всю документацию перечитал то, что квалификатор  hdpi под мой случай не подходит я понял. Но почему, если я установил квалификатор sw30000dp , ресурс берется из этой папки? Это означает, что ресурс брать из этой папки только если ширина больше 30000dp,  иначе  брать из def папки?

Comment: хоть sw3dp хоть sw3000dp , ни на одном экране не отдается предпочтение def папки. Так где же квалификатор, чтобы нужную мне логику реализовать